# BibLaTeX: how to check whether a category is non-empty?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to ask how can I check whether a category is non-epmty. There is a bibliography database and many of biblatex categories defined. I need to issue (in a cyclic way) `\printbibliography{category=XYZ}` only for the categories to which at least one item belongs. Is there something like `\ifcategoryempty{}`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in `\ifcategoryempty`, but it is easy to define one if you know how categories are implemented. Internally, a category is just a list named `blx@catg@<category name>` that contains all entry keys that belong to the category. So checking if a category is empty is as easy as checking that the list is empty.

If you want to print all categories that have at least one entry, you can use `\bibbycategory`. It will cycle through all defined categories (in the order they were declared) and prints a bibliography for each category that is non-empty. Make sure to define a bibliography heading for each category, so `biblatex` knows what to put as heading.

The MWE shows both `\ifcategoryempty` and `\bibbycategory`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{twoentries}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{oneentry}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{noentries}

\addtocategory{twoentries}{sigfridsson}
\addtocategory{twoentries}{nussbaum}
\addtocategory{oneentry}{geer}

\defbibheading{twoentries}{\section*{A First Category}}
\defbibheading{oneentry}{\section*{A Second Category}}
\defbibheading{noentries}{\section*{Nothing to see here}}

\newcommand*{\ifcategoryempty}[1]{\ifcsvoid{blx@catg@#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,geer}

\ifcategoryempty{twoentries}{T}{F}
\ifcategoryempty{oneentry}{T}{F}
\ifcategoryempty{noentries}{T}{F}

\bibbycategory
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Nussbaum 1978; Geer 1985//F F T//then follow two bibliographies]